# Python ctypes Structure packing can't be changed with inheritance

Tags: python, struct, ctypes, packing

I'm writing an application that uses `ctypes.Structure` to serialise data, and send it over a network.

So I'm using `_pack_ = 1` to remove those pesky padded bytes, which works.

```
from ctypes import *

class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('a', c_uint8),
        ('b', c_uint16),
    )

sizeof(A) == 4 # yep, expected that... 'a' takes up 2 bytes

class B(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = (
        ('a', c_uint8),
        ('b', c_uint16),
    )

sizeof(B) == 3 # also good, 'a' now occupies 1 byte only
```

However, I'd like to apply packing based on other criteria, but with the same content (same `_fields_`).
so I tried...

```
class C(A):
    _pack_ = 1

sizeof(C) == 4 # wait, what? Shouldn't this == 3
```

My actual implementation needs to be dynamic, so I'm using:

```
D = type(A.__name__, (A,), {'_pack_': 1})
sizeof(D) == 4 # same result as class C
```

Can anyone offer some wisdom on this one?

Comment: How about `class C(B)` instead of `class C(A)`? :^D  Similar for the `D` example.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: That does work, but still doesn't change packing by inheritance (ie: the parent class `B` is packed, so it's child `C` is _also_ packed). I need to _change_ the way a `Structure` is packed by setting `_pack_` with inheritance. Thanks all the same though.

Comment: Ah, don't think that is possible without redefining the base class.

Comment: Hmm that's sad... I've implemented a work around, but it's not ideal.